# Reading two lines where the program needs to output the positions where the numbers on each line match

Tags: python

The
program reads two lines of numbers from a file whose name is supplied on
the command line. The program outputs a list of indices where the numbers
on each line match.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9
3 4 4 4 9 6 1 2
```

so It should print [3,5] as the numbers in position 3 and position 5 match.

I've tried using while loops but I think my overall approach to the question is wrong and I've no idea how to solve it.

```
import sys

def main():
    try:
        li = []
        f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
        line1 = f.readline().split()
        line2 = f.readline().split()
        for k in line1:
            for v in line2:
                if k == v:
                    print(k)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File {} does not exist'.format(sys.argv[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

my code is printing:

```
1
2
3
4
4
4
6
9
```

but I need it to be printing the positions [3,5].

Comment: Would you like to discuss your repeated attempts to vandalise some of your questions?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is incorrect; you painstakingly check to see whether each value exists *anywhere* in the other loop, not at the same position.

```
        line1 = f.readline().split()
        line2 = f.readline().split()
        for k in line1:
            for v in line2:
                if k == v:
                    print(k)
```

Instead, loop through the positions:

```
for idx, val1 in enumerate(line1):
    if val1 == line2[idx]:
        print(idx)
```

Without `enumerate`:

```
for idx in len(line1):
    if line1[idx] == line2[idx]:
        print(idx)
```

Comment: is there another way to solve with out the enumerate? Thanks so much by the way!

Comment: Yes, one way would be to introduce a variable `idx=0` outside the for loop, and increment it at the end of the loop (but within the loop) with `idx += 1`. But using `enumerate` is considered more pythonic and it is probably recommended to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic solution exists:

```py
import sys


def main():
    try:
        with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
            for n, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(next(f).split(), next(f).split())):
                if a == b:
                    print(n)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File {} does not exist'.format(sys.argv[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This solves the same problem as indicated in the other answer (only compare matching pairs, instead of checking all against all), but using `zip()` gets around using indexing without duplicating the data and with less code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see values in position 3 and 5 matching from the sample data. My understanding is that he is looking for index position in each line that have the same values. The loops then should be:

```
for idx1, val1 in enumerate(line1):
    for idx2, val2 in enumerate(line2):
        if val1 == val2:
            print(idx1+1, idx2+1)
```

Comment: you start counting at position 0